# How to seperate phone number (area code, prefix, lineon) in phone book app C Programming

Tags: c, function

I just have a quick question - I've made this very simple phone book software which allows the user to input a maximum of three phone numbers, allows you to display the inputted numbers and exit. Simple enough, except, what I am trying to do, is have the phone number entered (ie. 1234567890) be displayed in a formatted way breaking the phone number down (ie. (123)-456-7890) I have created the formulas within the function "decompose" but it doesn't seem to be applying to the printf statement within the display phone numbers. If you could help, I would really appreciate it and be thankful!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3

void decompose(long long phone_number, int *area, int *prefix, int *lineno);

void decompose(long long phone_number, int *area, int *prefix, int *lineno) {
    *area = (int)(phone_number / (10000000));
    *prefix = (int)((phone_number % (10000000) / 10000));
    *lineno = (int)(phone_number % (10000));
}


struct PhoneBook_Contacts
{
    char FirstName[20]; //Entered First Name
    char LastName[20]; //Entered Last Name
    char PhoneNumber[20]; //Phone Number
}; //TypeDef to Modify structure name



   //Begin main function
int main(void)
{
    int area, prefix, lineno;
    int counter = 0; 
    int iSelection = 0; //Variable to use to select menu choice//Global counter variable used to keep track of number of contacts
                     //phone *phonebook; //Phonebook instance
                     //phonebook = (phone*)malloc(sizeof(phone) * 1); //Allocate memory for contacts
    struct PhoneBook_Contacts phonebook[3];



    printf("---=== Phone Numbers ===---\n\n");


    while (iSelection <= 4)
    {

        printf("1. Display Phone List\n");
        printf("2. Add a Number\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");
        scanf("%d", &iSelection);
        printf("\n");

        // Add Friend
        if (iSelection == 2)
        {
            if (counter == 3) {
                printf("ERROR!!! Phone Number List is Full\n");
                printf("\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("Add a Number\n");
                printf("============\n");
                scanf("%s", phonebook[counter].PhoneNumber);
                printf("\n");
                counter++;
            }
        } //End if
          //printf("%d\n", iSelection);
          //Print Phonebook Entries
        if (iSelection == 1)
        {
            int x = 0;
            printf("Phone Numbers\n");
            printf("==============\n");
            for (x = 0; x < counter; x++) //For loop to print entries
            {
                decompose(phonebook[x], &area, &prefix, &lineno);
                printf("%s\n", phonebook[x].PhoneNumber); //Contact's Phone Number
                printf("%d%d%d", area, prefix, lineno);
                printf("\n");
            }
            //printf("%d%d%d", area, prefix, lineno);
            //printf("\n");

            //End for loop
        } //End if

          //Exit Application
        if (iSelection == 0)
        {
            printf("Exiting Phone Number App. Good Bye!!!\n");
            break;
        } //End if

    } //End while
    return 0;
} //End main function
```

Comment: Your `printf()` is outside the loop. Be careful, your code is not so badly formatted, so there is no reason for this. You also have a `f` hanging after the last `printf()` inside the `if (iSelection == 1)` block.

Comment: Your code does not compile. :-/ Lots of missing parens and semicolons. You're passing in `struct PhoneBook_Contacts` to `decompose()` which expects a `long long`. Since you're already storing the phone number as a string, you should pull it apart as a string, not a number.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got rid of that f and moved the printf statements to inside the loop, but now Im having trouble compiling it within my SSH client (converting it from the .c source code to an executable. I get the errors:
phone_app_in_lab.c: In function âdecomposeâ:
phone_app_in_lab.c:9:41: error: expected â)â before â;â token
phone_app_in_lab.c:92:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Comment: Schwern, thank you for the reply. As you can probably tell from the code, I am a complete amateur at this, and unfortunately Im not sure how to pull it apart as a string...and I'll search for missing parens and semicolons

Comment: Added missing brackets and...unsure of the iSelection variable. Visual Studio insists it is missing a semicolon and that it is undefined...but it has a semicolon and is indeed defined...I updated the code above with changes

Comment: Okay, I added everything that was missing in terms or brackets and semicolons, now the only problem left seems to be the line:  decompose(phonebook[x], &area, &prefix, &lineno);
As Schwern stated, it says it isnt compatible with a long long...what can I edit to fix this?

Comment: Instead of taking a `long long`, take the type that you're trying to pass in.

Comment: Yes, I know, thank you for your answer. But I'm unsure how to do that. Where in the code do I have to change it? I tried changing "long long" within the function decompose to float, but that didn't solve the problem. I don't know what else to change